# Two scroll sync'ed divs that contains an image - how to prevent event backfire?

Tags: javascript, html

In my javascript webapp I ve two div's that display image contents.  This is a comparison tool, so two div's are sync'ed when scrolling using **onscroll** event handlers like below.

```js
var display1 = document.getElementById("display1");
var display2 = document.getElementById("display2");

function onScroll_1(event) {
  var display1 = document.getElementById("display1");
  var display2 = document.getElementById("display2");

  display2.scrollLeft = display1.scrollLeft;
  display2.scrollTop = display1.scrollTop;
}

function onScroll_2(event) {
  var display1 = document.getElementById("display1");
  var display2 = document.getElementById("display2");

  display1.scrollLeft = display2.scrollLeft;
  display1.scrollTop = display2.scrollTop;
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
}

#display1, #display2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 42%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="display1" onscroll="onScroll_1(event)">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>

  <div id="display2" onscroll="onScroll_2(event)">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Users can scroll the contents using scroll bars, dragging and other ways.

The problem is one event cause the other event in a loop, so the result is very jittery when scrolling sometimes.

I think I need to stop event firing, but all my attempts did not work.

I tried use removeEventListener at the beginning of the handler and add it back at the end of the handler,

```
function onScroll_1()
{
    display2.removeEventListener("scroll",onScroll_2);

    display2.scrollLeft = display1.scrollLeft;
    display2.scrollTop = display1.scrollTop;

    display2.addEventListener("scroll",onScroll_2);
}
function onScroll_2()
{
    display1.removeEventListener("scroll",onScroll_1);    

    display1.scrollLeft = display2.scrollLeft;
    display1.scrollTop = display2.scrollTop;

    display1.addEventListener("scroll",onScroll_1);
}
```

I also tried to use if statement with a flag to prevent the other handler from changing the scroll value which cause another event firing

```
var lock1 = false;
var lock2 = false; 
function onScroll_1()
{
    lock2 = true;

    if(lock1 == false){
        display2.scrollLeft = display1.scrollLeft;
        display2.scrollTop = display1.scrollTop;
    }
    lock2 = false;

}
function onScroll_2()
{
    lock1 = true;

    if(lock2 == false){
        display1.scrollLeft = display2.scrollLeft;
        display1.scrollTop = display2.scrollTop;
    }
    lock1 = false;
}
```

,and I tried other similar variants, but non of them really worked.  The events keep getting fired by scroll value change in  the event handlers.

How should I stop this event firing back?

Comment: You probably need to add and remove listeners based on hover, e.g if cursor hovers over left div, remove listener from right and vice versa.